# Moving divs up in tandem

Tags: jquery, css

How do I get images to slide up with each other? Like they are glued together at the end Y position).

For example, image X slides up from Y1 to Y2
meanwhile Image Z slides up from Y0 to Y1

It's like a film that moves together.

Here's the code I've been using - that slides div up from Y = 300px to  Y= 0 and then other div up from Y = 300 to Y = 0, but the slide up leaves a right background.

prefer to use barebones jquery and css.

```
var slides = this.$el.find('.slide');
slides.each(function (i, o) {
    $(o).css('display', 'none');
}.bind(this));

var oldIndex = this.slideIndex;
this.slideIndex++;
if ( this.slideIndex > slides.length) {
    this.slideIndex = 1;
}

if (slides) {
    slides.eq(this.slideIndex - 1).css('display', 'block');
    slides.eq(oldIndex).css('display', 'block');

    if (this.slideInterval) {
        clearInterval(this.slideInterval);
    }
    this.slideInterval = setTimeout(this.runSlides.bind(this), 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate on scroll library.

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Here you can set the delay with your desired intervals. And good thing is that it will work on viewport.